# Entity Framework Plus Core Filter

Tags: c#, entity-framework-plus

I did not find example for my case.

My model:

```
public class Data
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string? Name {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Property>? Properties { get; set; }
}

public partial class Property
{
    public int? ID              { get; set; }
    public string? Name         { get; set; }
    public string? Value        { get; set; }
    public int?    ParentID     { get; set; }

    public virtual Data? Parent { get; set; }
}
```

My query:

```
var condition = "x.Properties != null && x.Properties.Any( y => y.Name == \"Date\" && y.Value == \"12/11/2022\" )";

var result = context.Data.Include( x => x.Properties ).WhereDynamic( x => condition );
```

And everything works fine,

but I need something more complex:

```
var condition = "x.Properties != null && x.Properties.Any( y => y.Name == \"Date\" && y.Value != null && y.Value.ToDateTime(103) < DateTime.Parse(\"12/11/2022\") )";
```

Where **ToDateTime(103)** is my Extension method to convert string to DateTime.

I got Exception when execute query:

> Oops! No applicable member has been found for the expression. The error occurred for expression "." at position 3 near ".Where(x => x.Properties".

When I run above query using plain WHERE everything works

```
var result = context.Data.Include( x => x.Properties ).Where( x => x.Properties != null && x.Properties.Any( y => y.Name == \"Date\" && y.Value != null && y.Value.ToDateTime(103) < DateTime.Parse(\"12/11/2022\") )");
```

Comment: Can i just point out that running SQL queries that convert table data in the WHERE clause is a really bad idea, mostly because it is highly likely SQLS will not be able to use an index on that column, and minorly because it's a boatload of conversion ops every time you run a query. Format your desired DateTime to a string in 103 format and search by string, instead of converting a million string dates in the table, into a DateTime every time you query. `WHERE someDateStringColumn = @p103string` would be better than `WHERE CONVERT(DATE, someDateStringColumn, 103) = @pDate`

Answer (score 0):

Per this [github issue](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/issues/564) you must register your extension method before using it:

```
EvalManager.DefaultContext.RegisterType(typeof(Your.DateTimeExtensionsClass));
```

Comment: You helped. Everything works